# mocking internal classes with mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, junit4

i have a class under Test which is marked as "interal"

```
internal class UnderTest{
    fun methodToTest(){}
}
```

In my JUnit Test i want test UnderTest 
    import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.mock

```
class SimpleTest{
    val mock = mock<UnderTest>()

    @Test
    fun test(){
        assertThat(....)
    } 
}
```

And here it gets a bit strange, as Android Studio complains first that UnderTest is not visible "public property exposes it's private type". Thats because UnderTest is marked as internal.

I changed the Test itself to be internal, which results that the compiler is happy again:

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.mock

internal class SimpleTest{
    val mock = mock<UnderTest>()

    @Test
    fun test(){
        assertThat(....)
    } 
}
```

Running this test results in an mockito exception like in the old mockito versions

```
Cannot mock/spy class com.name.UnderTest
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
- final class
```

I want to write Unit Test for those internal classes, but how without removing the internal modifier from UnderTest class ?

Thanks

Comment: checkout powermockito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not that the class is `internal` (it's equivalent to `public` within the same module) but rather that it's `final`. By default all classes in Kotlin are `final` unless you mark them with `open`.

So if you want to mock your class you should mark it as `internal open class Xyz`.
Note that there's a Maven/Gradle plugin that automatically opens all classes for you: [all-open plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#all-open-compiler-plugin).

For example, given the following Kotlin class:

```
internal open class Foo
```

The following unit test passes:

```
class FooTest {
    @Test
    fun shouldPass() {
        Mockito.mock(Foo::class.java)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. never seen internal open before so far. I was able to mock using a simple unit test class